# Modify Mono if other Mono is empty in project Reactor?

Tags: kotlin, project-reactor

I'm having a `Mono` that I want to modify when other `Mono` is empty.

First `Mono`:

```
deviceRepository.getDevice(deviceId, userId): Mono<Device>
```

Second `Mono`:

```
registrationRepository.canRegister(deviceId) : Mono<DeviceRegistrationInfo>
```

What I want to achieve is return modified `Mono<Device>` when `canRegister` returns empty mono for a given `deviceId`:

```
device.copy(status = DeviceStatus.REGISTRATION_FAILED)
```

Similarly I want to modify each emission of `Flux<Device>` for combination of:

```
deviceRepository.getDevices(userId) : Flux<Device>
```

and

```
registrationRepository.getAllRegistrationInfos(): Flux<DeviceRegistrationInfo>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by @piotr szybicki answer I've came up with following answer:

```
    val canRegister: Mono<Optional<PreRegistrationInfo>> = preRegistrationRepository.canRegister(deviceId)
    val foundDevice: Mono<Device> = deviceRepository.getDevice(deviceId, userId);

    return canRegister.flatMap {
        when {
            !it.isPresent -> foundDevice.map(this::overrideStatusIfNeeded)
            else -> foundDevice
        }
    }
}

private fun overrideStatusIfNeeded(it: Device) = if (it.status == DeviceStatus.ADDED) {
    it.copy(status = DeviceStatus.REGISTRATION_FAILED)
} else {
    it
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just using streams it is impossible to do what you want. Both streams and reactive streams are not design for this type of conditional logic. It is one of the biggest minuses to the framework. And it might be addressed when the pattern matching will come in java 13 or 14.

But we are not totally out of options. As Optional comes to a resque. My example is in Java but i'm sure it is enough for you to start.

It will also work for the Flux.

```
@Test
public void c(){
    //Mono<Optional<DeviceRegistrationInfo>> second = Mono.just(Optional.ofNullable(new DeviceRegistrationInfo()));
    Mono<Optional<DeviceRegistrationInfo>> second = Mono.just(Optional.empty());
    Mono<Device> device_ = Mono.just(new Device());

    second
            .map( info -> info.map( t -> device_) )  //you can put what you want in that map function and it will be executed only if optional is there
            .filter(Optional::isPresent)
            .flatMap(Optional::get)
            .subscribe(System.out::println);

}
```